# ERROR running force:source:retrieve: This command is required to run from within an SFDX project

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

I was able to create a project in VS code. Also able to authenticate the org. In the package.xml when i right click & click on "SFDX : Retrieve source in Manifest from Org" - i'm getting the following error message :-

UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
ERROR running force:source:retrieve:  This command is required to run from within an SFDX project.

It ended with exit code 1.

Any pointers to resolve this will be really helpful.

TIA.

[image]

Comment: are you running the command in the appropriate path? maybe you can share a screenshot of your directory and project, same for the context of where you are running the command?

Comment: I din't run the command. I right clicked in the package.xml file & clicked on the option to retrieve from Manifest.

Comment: if you run it using the command line it works normally then?

Comment: Added screen shot for better clarity on this issue.

Comment: Never tried running this in Command line.

Comment: can you try running it in the command line?

Comment: the error indicates that you are not running/executing this command in the context of an SFDX project

Comment: could you give me link to a blog.. which shows steps to do this using CLI

Answer (score 5):

Paths starting with `\\` ([UNC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dfsc/149a3039-98ce-491a-9268-2f5ddef08192)) are not supported. You would need to [map the drive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026635/windows-map-a-network-drive) to a local drive letter in order to use the network drive effectively. The latter error ("this command is required to run...") is simply a symptom of the first error.

Comment: The one thing I'd add is that you'll need to reopen your project from the mapped drive once you've done this.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue, I was creating project with SFDX:Create Project with manifest with default path.

I manually selected local C drive folder and **SFDX commands started working.**